# Google Directions XML Feed stopped working - code haven't changed

Tags: php, xml

I have a PHP file that intercepts and XML google feed for creating directions. Nothing has changed yet the file now produces no results. I have no idea why. So I have set up a testing page in the hope one of you can see what the hell is going on.

It is as if the feed url has changed, but it hasn't as I've checked that.

Here is the test page, listing 2 post codes taken from a regular get expression. A similar script is also used on another part of our site that has failed too. It's as if we have been blocked.

http://www.golfbrowser.com/Actions/directions.php?start=S173ne&end=SL42ES

And the PHP

```
<?php 

$start = $_GET['start'];
$end = $_GET['end'];

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='.$start.'&destination='.$end.'&sensor=false');


// data to fetch
$startlat = $xml->xpath("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/start_location/lat");
$startlng = $xml->xpath("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/start_location/lng");
$endlat = $xml->xpath("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/end_location/lat");
$endlng = $xml->xpath("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/end_location/lng");


$start = $xml->xpath("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/start_address");
$end = $xml->xpath("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/end_address");

$start = (string)$start[0];
$end = (string)$end[0];

$startlat = (string)$startlat[0];
$startlng = (string)$startlng[0];

$endlat = (string)$endlat[0];
$endlng = (string)$endlng[0];


// Route Information

$distance = $xml->xpath("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/distance/value");
$duration = $xml->xpath("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/duration/value");

$distance = (string)$distance[0];
$duration = (string)$duration[0];

$duration = round(($duration / 60), 0);

if ($duration > 60)
{
  $hours = round(($duration / 60),0). ' hour and ';
  $minutes = $duration % 60 . ' minutes';
}
if ($duration == 60)
{
  $hours = round(($duration / 60),0). ' hour';
  $minutes == '';
}
if ($duration >= 120)
{
  $hours = round(($duration / 60),0). ' hours and ';
  $minutes = $duration % 60 . ' minutes';
}
if ($duration < 60)
{
   $minutes = $duration % 60 . ' minutes';
}

$distancekm = round(($distance * 0.001), 1);
$distancem = round(($distance * 0.000621371192), 1);


// Directions

$directions = $xml->xpath("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/step");





// Compilation

$outputo = '
<a class="dirtotal" onclick="titoall()"><b>Route Overview </b>'.$distancem.' miles ('.$distancekm.' km) <br />about '.$hours.' '.$minutes.'</a>';

$outputs = '<a class="dirstart" onclick="tito('.$startlat.', '.$startlng.')"><b>'.$start.'</b></a>';

$output = '';
$distancem = '';
$distancekm = '';
$duration = '';

$order = 0;

foreach ($directions as $direct) {

    $latitude = $direct->start_location->lat;
    $longitude = $direct->start_location->lng;

    $output .= '<a class="dir" onclick="tito('.$latitude.', '.$longitude.')"><span class="tit">'.($order += 1).'</span><div>';

    if($distancekm !== '') {

    $output .= 'Drive '.$distancem.' miles ('.$distancekm.' km) then ';

    }


    $instructions =  $direct->html_instructions;
    $duration = $direct->duration->value;
    $distance = $direct->distance->value;

    $distancekm = round(($distance * 0.001), 1);
    $distancem = round(($distance * 0.000621371192), 1);


    $output .= $instructions;

    $output .= '</div><span class="end"></span></a>';

}

$outpute =
'<a class="dirend" onclick="tito('.$endlat.', '.$endlng.')"><b>'.$end.'</b></a>';


// output

$outputs = $outputo.$outputs.$output.$outpute;

echo $outputs;


?>
```

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: I have turned the feed to a file and printed the result to find the response OVER QUERY LIMIT

Comment: Yes it appears to be working fine for me, I guess you did hit a [usage limit](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits)

Answer (score 0):

You hit a usage limit: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits

Try caching Google's responses and showing them to future users searching for the same directions.